# How to transfer hex strings to []byte directly in Go?

Tags: string, go, hex, slice

Question is simple,

how to transfer `"46447381"` in to `[]byte{0x46,0x44,0x73,0x81}`?

Comment: That would be more complicated than I thought, because I just use hex.EncodeToString, I wonder why I cannot use kind of this function to let it back.

Comment: @EdmDroid yes question is simple, but that means I want a simple answer.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Simply use the [`hex.DecodeString()`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/#DecodeString) function:

```
s := "46447381"

data, err := hex.DecodeString(s)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Printf("% x", data)
```

**Output:**

```
46 44 73 81
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/3o67X5bBn3).

**Note:**

If you just simply print the byte slice using `fmt.Println(data)`, the printed values will be in decimal format that's why it won't match your input `string` (because it is specified in hexadecimal format).
Output of `fmt.Println(data)` would be:

```
[70 68 115 129]
```

These are the same numbers just in decimal base.

Comment: You're right, I'm so stupid, I thought that should not be transferred into dec, but indeed it should be, thanks.
http://play.golang.org/p/S_blDzfpN7